# glewInit is failed

Tags: c++, glew

#Why glew library init failed?

I use SDL2 glew and opengl in my program.I try to test glew is initial successfully
or not,but it always failed.I had created context for openGL,but it still did not work.
some details are as follows.

Code block:
'''C++

```
mWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Game Programming in C++ (Chapter 6)", 100, 100,
static_cast<int>(mScreenWidth), static_cast<int>(mScreenHeight), SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

if (!mWindow)
{
    SDL_Log("Failed to create window: %s", SDL_GetError());
    return false;
}

// Create an OpenGL context
mContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mWindow);

// Initialize GLEW
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
{
    SDL_Log("Program Failed");
    SDL_Log("Failed to initialize GLEW.");
    return false;
}
```

run result are as follows.

INFO: Program Failed.
INFO: Failed to initialize GLEW.

I want to know how can I solve the problem

Comment: What's the return value of `glewInit()`? Does it work if you disable glewExperimental?

Comment: The value of glewInit() is 1 ,I disable glewExperimental but it still not work

Comment: Is `mContext` non-null?

Comment: I had tested. the mContext is null . That should be the reason. Why is it null?

Comment: Use [`SDL_GetError`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError) to get the error string.

Comment: The value of "SDL_GetError()" is wglMakeCurrent():   Invalid handle

Comment: How to correct the problem,**wglMakeCurrent():handle is invaild**.